# How can i send push alerts using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, mobile, push-notification

I want to know if one can send push alerts using rails.
If yes, is there any tutorial or plugin for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. https://github.com/samsoffes/apple_push_notification

Comment: can i send push notifications to blackberry and android phone using this.

Comment: Not very sure about Android, but Blackberry, Apple and Windows phones all have service provided by the respective makers with which you have to register first. Blackberry has a tutorial, you can find the details about it from the blackberry site, afaik there isnt one solution for all push notifications.